# Personalizar el sistema de correo electrónico de devise

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, devise

bueno tengo un problema estoy personalizando los mails de devise pero no se coloca el estilo css como veras en la imagen, utilizo a través de otra aplicación para emular un servidor donde estan los archivos de estilo por lo que no tiene puerto 3000, el punto es que quiero que tenga efecto el estilo css en los correos electronicos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te aconsejo para la próxima, agrega tu código como texto en vez de un pantallazo, es más fácil y accesible para tod@s. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

No puedes agregar archivos css a un email, los estilos tienen que estar embebidos dentro del código html que envías.
Para lograr embeber los estilos fácilmente en rails, puedes probar a usar [roadie-rails](https://github.com/Mange/roadie-rails) o [premailer-rails](https://github.com/fphilipe/premailer-rails) que son las gemas más usadas (que conozco) para ese propósi.

Comment: me ayudarías a usar no entiendo mucho esas gemas ni de la instalación coloco  gem 'premailer-rails'
 luego que hago

Comment: De [la documentación](https://github.com/fphilipe/premailer-rails#usage) `premailer-rails processes all outgoing emails by default`. O sea, no debes hacer nada, solo con agregar la gema a tu proyecto debería ser suficiente.